# How to rebuilding a module in PSFS framework correctly?

Tags: php, frameworks

We have a PHP project built with PSFS framework, but we're stuck trying to rebuilding an existing module.

Which "Controller Type" should I choose when rebuilding the module? Could someone explain to me what each option means?

[image: Rebuilding Module]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to regenerate a module, you have to decide the parent class to extend from. In that case you have some options:

- Without authentication (normal)
- With user authentication (for APIs services or logged html sections)
- With admin authentication (that requires the Basic Auth for admins)

You can see another option when you need to extend from your own class that controls all the authentication, in this case you have to complete the input with the fully namespace and PSFS automatically extends the principal module and the API classes from this specific class instead of the PSFS base classes. The selector before will be ignored in case of setting something as custom namespace.